# Select case em duas tabelas

Tags: mysql, select

Tenho 4 tabelas:

```
Saida{
id int,
idDestino int,
idProduto int,
tipoDestino int,
quant int,
data date,
solicitante varchar}

Paciente{
id int, 
nome varchar}

Unidade{
id int,
nome varchar}

Produto{
id int,
nome varchar,
quant int}
```

A tabela `saida` registra os itens do estoque que saíram para Pacientes ou Unidades.

No meu programa, eu faço o seguinte: se saida.tipoDestino for igual a 0, então a saída foi pra um Paciente. se saida.tipoDestino for igual a 1, então a saída foi pra uma Unidade.

Até aí tudo bem. O que preciso de vocês é fazer um select +- assim:

```
SELECT
saida.id, saida.data,
(CASE saida.tipoDestino WHEN 0 THEN paciente.nome WHEN 1 THEN unidade.descricao END) as Destino,
produto.descricao, saida.quant
FROM
saida, paciente, unidade, produto
WHERE
paciente.id = saida.idDestino OR
unidade.id = saida.idDestino
```

Preciso que no campo `Destino` seja informado o nome do `Paciente` ou da `Unidade`, de acordo com o valor do campo `tipoDestino`.

O resultado até retorna valores, mas mostra muitos campos repetidos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma pequena modificação!
Tente este script não testado e poste o resultado.

```
SELECT
  s.id,
  s.data,
  case
    when s.tipoDestino = 1 then p.nome
    else u.descricao
  end as Destino,
  pr.descricao,
  s.quant
FROM
  saida s
  left join paciente p on (p.id = s.idDestino)
  left join unidade u on (u.id = s.idDestino)
  left join produto pr on (pr.id = s.idProduto)
```

Comment: funciona em parte. primeiro ele verifica se idDestino existe na tabela paciente, caso não exista é que ele procura na tabela unidade. o código não faz referência à variável tipoDestino para saber em qual tabela irá procurar.

Comment: Verdade, obrigado... foi corrigido!